# how to display results from an api to your views in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I seem to be getting an error when i run my app:

```
getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

I think that the error is cause there is no connection between the app and the server where the api is been retrieved using a service.I am using `RestClient` gem to access the requests.

```
#services/get_games.rb
class GetGames
  def self.get_games
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(
      method: :get,
      url: 'https://api-2445582011268.apicast.io.json',
      headers: {user_key: ENV["IGDB_API"], accept:'application/json'}
    )
  end
end

#games_controller
def index
    @response = JSON.parse(GetGames.get_games)
    @games = Game.all
end
```

Comment: The error you are getting is because https://api-2445582011268.apicast.io.json is an invalid domain name.

Comment: The domain name is Okey. It seems the the error I had was that I was passing the headers wrongly. It works :)

Comment: `io.json` is not a valid domain, but, I'm glad you made it work.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you take off the `.json` in the `url`, the error will go away.

Comment: Didn't solve the issue...now getting 403: Forbidden error

Comment: So it seems you need the proper credentials.